# Yii2- Query result array returning no values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, yii2, resultset

I am new to `Yii2 php`. I have a **query** which is giving me **some results**.

```
$result_set = "SELECT m.`id`,ogpd.`meter_serial`, m.`meter_status`  FROM `ogp_header`ogph
INNER JOIN `ogp_detail` ogpd ON ogph.`id` = ogpd.`ogp_id`
INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ogpd.`meter_id` = m.`id`
WHERE ogph.`issuer` = $ogp_id"; // here $ogp_id is 88
```

**The output is**

[image]

Now I want is to check the value of column `meter_status` in the above `$result_set`.

So after searching I have found that I have to return the query result in array. So after seeing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39343541/8919244) I have done changes like bellow.  Below is **what I have done**

```
 $result =Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT m.`id`,ogpd.`meter_serial`, m.`meter_status`  FROM `ogp_header`ogph
                        INNER JOIN `ogp_detail` ogpd ON ogph.`id` = ogpd.`ogp_id`
                        INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ogpd.`meter_id` = m.`id`
                        WHERE ogph.`issuer` = $ogp_id")->queryAll();

          var_dump($result);
          exit();
```

Now when I run my code I am getting `array(0) { }`. I don't know why it's not giving me null array.

How can I achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try binding the ogp_id variable: $post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT .. your query... ogph.issuer =:ogp_id')
           ->bindValue(':ogp_id', $ogp_id)->queryAll();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that $ogp_id is correctly assigned  and try using a proper binding

```
  $ogp_id =  88;
  $result =Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT m.id, ogpd.meter_serial, m.meter_status  
                    FROM ogp_header ogph
                    INNER JOIN ogp_detail ogpd ON ogph.id = ogpd.ogp_id
                    INNER JOIN meters m ON ogpd.meter_id = m.id
                    WHERE ogph.issuer = :ogp_id ")
                     ->bindValue(':ogp_id', $ogp_id)
                    ->queryAll();

      var_dump($result);
      exit();
```

and remove unuseful backtics  when not needed

Comment: Actually I was passing the wrong variable. Now its done and working